# Eclipse Mars Autocomplete Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

In Eclipse Luna, I would be able to type `syso` followed by Ctrl+Space, and it would autocomplete as `System.out.println();`, even though the actual template in Eclipse Preferences was listed as `sysout`. I was able to type part of the `sysout` and still have it autocomplete.

In Eclipse Mars, I no longer can do that for some reason. If I type `syso` followed by Ctrl + Space, I get a autocomplete window which prompts me to select a statement from the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywdju.png).

Is there a way to fix this behaviour to what it was like in Eclipse Luna?

Comment: Well you just have to type enter don't you ? Apparently this version also looks to words in the name (identified by Camel Case), this is way there are several matches

Answer (score 2):

I had the same experience and it was pretty annoying. But it was resolved by changing the preferences and adding more characters to "Auto activation triggers for Java".

To do so, please follow these steps:

1. Click on "Windows" menu and select "Preferences".
2. Search for Content Assist (Java > Editor).
3. Change "Auto activation triggers for Java" based on your preferences. (The default is only ".", I usually change it to ".abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").

The good thing about it is that you just need to press "Enter" after typing "syso" without pressing Ctrl+Space.

Reference: [Java Content Assist Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-content-assist.htm)

Comment: A link to another question is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: Thanks @whipdancer for your comment. I read the documentation by StackOverFlow about "How do I write a good answer?" thoroughly and edited my answer. Please let me know if there is anything that I can improve. –